# Copiar dados de um banco de dados para outro?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Boa tarde, sou iniciante em sql server e me deparei com uma situação que me surgiu essa dúvida. Gostaria de saber se é possível copiar uma tabela de um database para outro, na situação em que ambas estejam no mesmo servidor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Caso não fique claro o texto, seria como na imagem mostra, os dois bancos tem exatamente as mesmas tabelas, mas o "ORIGEM" tem na tabela dbo.cidadesibge vários registros que eu gostaria de colocar no banco "DESTINO" na mesma tabela dbo.cidadesibge. Procurei em algumas páginas, li que haviam algumas formas, mas não consegui nenhuma resposta que me esclarecesse como realizar. Pensei em realizar com "Select * Into" também não consegui nenhuma forma de funcionar nesse caso, se alguém puder me esclarecer como realizar agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: @bfavaretto `INSERT INTO Destino.Schema.Tabela (Column1, ..) SELECT Column1,.. FROM ORIGEM.Schema.Tabla;`

Comment: Ops, tem razão @Sami

Comment: Você quer copiar toda informação da BD ORIGEM ou apenas os dados da tabela dbo.cidadesibge?

Comment: na situação exemplo que dei seria o caso de copiar os dados da tabela origem para a tabela destino, sabendo que as duas são idênticas em colunas e nome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que as estruturas de tabela são as mesmas, aconselho você a usar o seguinte comando:

INSERT INTO DESTINO.dbo.cidadesibge

SELECT * FROM ORIGEM.dbo.cidadesibge

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: deu certo, exatamente como eu queria... muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score -2):

Você poderia fazer um backup destes dados e executar neste banco aonde iria inserir esses dados e tabelas. Eu pelo menos iria fazer isso.

Comment: Ele quer fazer de uma tabela só e não do banco inteiro. Esta sua solução iria sobrescrever os outros dados gerando outros problemas.